# Configure Prometheus Scraping To Occur At Half Past The Hour

Tags: prometheus

I have a process (in python) that starts on the hour, every hour. It takes about 20 minutes to complete. I'm using the Push Gateway to send prometheus metrics for the start and end of the process.

I've created another script that produces metrics about the process. However, those metrics are only available and relevant after the 20 minute process is completed.

Can I make a scrape_config where the interval is "30 minutes past the hour"?
A comparable cronjob would be "30 * * * *"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. Scrapes are staggered across the scrape interval to balance out the load.

What you probably want to do is have the 2nd script also push to the pushgateway.